# Displaying Full Screen Background in Jquery Mobile 1.1.1

Tags: jquery, css

I have a 640 w and 960 h background and I am using the following code. My Background displays but it cuts off on the right side and shows a 15% grey color background.

If I change to background-size:  100% 100%, the background stretches. Any ideas. background-size:cover also scales the background

```
body {
                background-image: url(images/splash_bk.png);
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-attachment:fixed;
                /*background-size:100% 100%;*/
                background-size:contain;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change background-size:contain to background-size:cover

I hope this is helpful

Comment: thanks, but background-size:cover also does not work. It scales the background and stretches it

Comment: What kind of smart phone you use for testing

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">